# PHP cannot unset session variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, session-variables

I cannot unset a session variable used on a search filter. When clicking domain.com/index.php?filter=clear nothing happens and the filter is not cleared.

I am using a mixture of php and JS to update the table using AJAX

**PHP:**

```
/**
 * Clears the current filter
 */
function clear()
{
    unset($_SESSION['filter']);

    // Clear current page
    unset($_SESSION['arctic_page']);
}
```

}

**JS:**

```
clear: function()
{
    // Show loading image
    new Element('img', { src: '/images/loading.gif' }).setStyle('float', 'right').injectTop(Issues.container.getElement('h2'));

    // Create AJAX request
    new Ajax('index.php',
    {
        method: 'get',
        data: 'ajax=true&filter=clear',
        update: 'issue_list',
        onComplete: Issues.initialise
    }).request();
}
```

Comment: Have you added `session_start();` on top ?

Comment: Yes, session_start(); is included in my init.php (before filters are loaded)

Comment: Are you actually getting the same session ID on the main page as you are on the ajax request?

Comment: Where are you calling the `clear()` function?

Comment: Yes, i am returning the same session ID. and the clear() function is on a hyperlink domain.com/index.php?filter=clear

Comment: That's only the function definition, you have to call it explicitly, something like: `(isset($_GET['filter']) && ($_GET['filter']=='clear'))?clear():'';`

Comment: How are you certain that the `clear()` function is called?

Comment: whats the best way to check this?

Comment: Since you are calling this through AJAX, try putting `echo "<script>console.log('clear executed');</script>"` inside your `function clear(){}`and check your developer tool to see if 'clear executed' message has been printed, if not, try pasting the code in my above comment with your PHP part.

Comment: OKay, so looking at the console i can see
    'ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined' on line 108 of my JS which is new Ajax.Request('index.php',
{
    method: 'get',
    data: 'ajax=true&filter=clear',
    update: 'issue_list',
    onComplete: Issues.initialise
});

Answer (score 0):

It looks like prototype JS, correct? It's been a while for me, but I thought this was the correct syntax:

```
new Ajax.Request('index.php',
{
    method: 'get',
    data: 'ajax=true&filter=clear',
    update: 'issue_list',
    onComplete: Issues.initialise
});
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work either. I'm actually using a slightly modified version of Arctic Bug Tracker